# how to find closest value in datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, winforms, datagridview, listbox

I have 1 data grid view and 1 list box. In data gird view I collected data like that:

```
10
13
16
19
22
25 
28
31
34
37
42
...
```

I want to take values from data grid view to list box which are can be divided to 10 or which gives the smallest difference when divided by 10. The data that I want to add to list box according to data example above;

```
10 
19 
31
42
...
```

And here is my code;
  **EDITED**

```
  private void btnAccModeStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    if(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)%10==0)
    {
        listBoxACC.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    }
    else if(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)%10!=0);
    {
        // I don't know what I should write here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should define the maximum difference allowed, then only one `if` should do it, like so: `if (max_difference - (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)%10) >= 0){...}`.

Comment: in this post you decided to take 19 and not 22 into your list? how come you changed your mind?

Comment: @MongZhu To minimze the error I decided to get closest value whatever it is higher or lower than the decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I had a hard time deciphering your question, but I think I've got it now.

Basically, for `10, 20, 30, 40, 50, ...` you want the values in your list, that are closest to, right.

This is exactly what I would do. Not iterating over the list of items in your grid, but iterating over the target value. You could achieve the desired like this

```
private IEnumerable<int> GetValuesClosestToMultiplesOfTen(IEnumerable<int> input)
{
    foreach(var multipleOfTen in GetMultiplesOfTenUpTo(input.Max())
    {
        yield return GetClosestValue(input, multipleOfTen);
    }
}
```

The method iterates over a `IEnumerable<int>` of multiples of 10 and returns the closest value from your `input` list.

Of course you'll have to implement the following two methods, too

```
private IEnumerable<int> GetMultiplesOfTenUpTo(int upTo)
{
    int remainder = upTo % 10;
    if(remainder < 5)
    {
        upTo = (upTo / 10) * 10; // is rounded to the next lower multiple of 10
    }
    else 
    {
        upTo = (upTo / 10) * 10  + 10; //  to the next higher multiple of ten
    }

    for(int multiple = 10; multiple <= upTo; multiple += 10)
    {
        yield return multiple;
    }
}

private int GetClosestValue(IEnumerable<int> input, int targetValue)
{
    return input.Select(i => new{Value = i, Distance = i-targetValue})
        .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.Distance))
        .First().Value;
}
```

This is definitely not the most elegant or the most performant solution, but this should work out. (Aside the possibility that for example 19 and 21 have the same distance to 20 - you'll have to adapt the algorithm to your means.)

**Please Note:** Under certain circumstances, this code may yield duplicate entries. If this behavior is not desired you'll have to handle this case, e.g. by removing values below the last multiple of ten.

**Edit**

You can use this snippet to get your values from the DataGridView

```
var values = dataGridView.Rows
    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[0].Value))
```

And then

```
var closestToMultiplesOfTen = GetValuesClosestToMultiplesOfTen(values);
foreach(var item in closestToMultiplesOfTen)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: thanks you for your reply. You understand what I want to do right but could you tell me how can I integrate your code to my button and how can I collect right values to listbox?

Comment: I will, but later today. Busy now.

Comment: Thanks you again. I will wait for the answer.

Comment: İt gives an error in this part `var values = dataGridView.Rows.Select(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[0].Value))`.It says `Select`doesn't contain in datagridview library.

Comment: Yes I adapted control names.

Comment: Okay, this one is pretty basic. Add `using System.Linq;` to your using directives. But, as a programmer you should be able to do quite some research by yourself. I bet when you paste that error to Google it will yield useful information.

Comment: Thanks you for your advice and for your answer  Before I wrote here as error I had already searched it and couldn't find the answer. By the way I had already added `using system.linq` too before trying your code. Thanks you again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150679/discussion-between-paul-kertscher-and-quanthema).